# Find UsingDirectiveSyntax that belongs to InvocationExpressionSyntax

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

In the code below, the "Console.WriteLine" call needs the "System" using directive to work. I already have a UsingDirectiveSyntax object for "using System" and an InvocationExpressionSyntax object for "Console.Writeline". But how can I know, using Roslyn, that the InvocationExpressionSyntax and UsingDirectiveSyntax objects belong to each other?

```
using System;       
public class Program
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you'd find anything in the syntax tree - you'd need semantics applied before it's decided which specific class `Console` refers to.

Comment: Yes indeed, but even when I have the Symbol object of both, how can I link them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method symbol of the `InvocationExpressionSyntax` has a member `ContainingNamespace`, that one should equal the namespace symbol that you get from retrieving the symbol of the using directive. The trick there is to use the `Name` member as starting point for querying the semantic model, since the entire `UsingDirectiveSyntax` won't give you a symbol.

[Try this LINQPad query](https://gist.github.com/tiesmaster/30b10d66ea0678471fb1ea3968344abe) (or copy it into a console project), and you'll get `true` on the last line of the query ;)

```
// create tree, and semantic model
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
    using System;
    public class Program
    {
       public static void Main()
       {
          Console.WriteLine(""Hello World"");
       }
   }");
var root = tree.GetRoot();

var mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("SO-39451235", syntaxTrees: new[] { tree }, references: new[] { mscorlib });
var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);

// get the nodes refered to in the SO question

var usingSystemDirectiveNode = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<UsingDirectiveSyntax>().Single();
var consoleWriteLineInvocationNode = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>().Single();

// retrieve symbols related to the syntax nodes

var writeLineMethodSymbol = (IMethodSymbol)model.GetSymbolInfo(consoleWriteLineInvocationNode).Symbol;
var namespaceOfWriteLineMethodSymbol = (INamespaceSymbol)writeLineMethodSymbol.ContainingNamespace;

var usingSystemNamespaceSymbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(usingSystemDirectiveNode.Name).Symbol;

// check the namespace symbols for equality, this will return true

namespaceOfWriteLineMethodSymbol.Equals(usingSystemNamespaceSymbol).Dump();
```